# Why does my page stay blank after I press submit?

Tags: php, html, forms, email

```html
    <form method="post" action="mail_handler.php">
      <div class="col-sm-7 slideanim">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
          <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Naam" type="text" required>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
          <input class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Telefoonnummer" type="text" required>
        </div> 
          <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
          <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="msg" name="msg" placeholder="Bericht" rows="5"></textarea><br>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" id="submit" type="submit">Verstuur</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>    
    </form>
```

I've tried to make this form work, but for some reason it just doesn't send the E-mail, also it stays blank after I press the submit button. I've tried eveything within my reach to fix it, it must be something pretty obvious that I keep overlooking. (I work with the Cpanel to check if the mail is sending, so there is a smtp server available).

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $msg=$_POST['msg'];

    $to='info@sync-development.nl'; // Receiver Email ID, Replace with your email ID
    $subject='Form Submission';
    $message="Name :".$name."\n"."Phone :".$phone."\n"."Wrote the following :"."\n\n".$msg;
    $headers="From: ".$email;

    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
        echo "<h1>Bedankt voor uw bericht!"." ".$name.", Wij nemen zo snel mogelijk contact met u op.</h1>";
    }
    else{
        echo "Er is iets fout gegaan, probeer het alstublieft opnieuw.";
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: Your submit button doesn't have a name attribute `name="submit"`

Answer (score 4):

You should add name attribute to the button so replace

```
<button class="btn btn-default pull-right" id="submit" type="submit">Verstuur</button>
```

by

```
<button class="btn btn-default pull-right" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit">Verstuur</button>`
```

Comment: It works, I feel ashamed that I didn't see this at first.. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<button class="btn btn-default pull-right" name="submit" id="submit" type="submit">Verstuur</button>
```

Comment: Why should anyone "*try this*"? What did you change, and why?

Comment: I am only suggesting to Timothy. He forget to give name inside the button tag.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button class="btn btn-default pull-right" id="submit" type="submit">Verstuur</button>
```

You are missing **name** attribute and your **php handler** doesn't get in the if **true** condition, because it can't find *"submit"* key. Change your **HTML Button** like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-default pull-right" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit">Verstuur</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either add a name="" attribute to button or relay on some other var. Also double check that passed variables are not empty string by using `!empty()`.

So replace:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
```

with:

```
if (!empty($_POST['email'])){
```

or simply:

```
if (!empty($_POST)){
```

Comment: Are you sure about that? "*Button's values are not passed over with POST array*"?

Comment: @Qirel There are only passed when you set name attr on them, but you shouldn't relay on static value but on the values passed in.

Comment: That's more accurate. They're only sent when they have a name, but their values are sent if it does ;-)

Comment: My bad, it's just not that common to use button's values instead of hidden input fields.